# Setting up integral for a manifold

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry

$a(t),b(t),f(t)$ are real valued functions of $C^1$ on $[0,1]$ with $f(t)>0$. Suppose $M$ is a 2-manifold in $\Bbb R^3$ whose intersection with the plane $z=t$ is the circle

$$(x-a(t))^2+(y-b(t))^2=(f(t))^2; z=t$$ if $0\le t \le1$ and is empty otherwise

Set up an integral for the area of $M$.

Can someone please show me a way how to go about this? I think I need to parametrize $M$, but I do not know how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the intersection at $z = t$ is a circle centered at $(a(t), b(t))$ and with radius $f(t)$ (So $f(t) >0$ is used here). To parametrize a circle which is located at the plane $z = t$, we have

$$X(t, \theta) = (a(t) + f(t) \cos\theta, b(t) + f(t) \sin \theta, t)$$

and you can use this parametrization to calculate the area.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please tell me how you arrive at that parametrization?

Comment: This is the usual parametrization of a circle with center $(a, b)$ and radius $f$ given. For example $(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$ parametrizes the unit circle centered at the origin. @MarionCrane